# How to wrap text around framed floats in ConTeXt?

Tags: floats, context, framed, backgrounds

The goal is to embed an image into a coloured box with text. I tried with \placefigure and \starthangaround. They work fine outside a frame, but once put inside a frame the text collides with the image.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\setupcolors[state=start]

\starttext

  \placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigure[placeholder][width=27mm,height=27mm]}
  \input knuth

  \startframedtext[width=broad, background=color, backgroundcolor=green]
    \placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigure[placeholder][width=27mm,height=27mm]}
    \input knuth
  \stopframedtext

  \startframedtext[width=broad, background=color, backgroundcolor=green]
    \starthangaround{\externalfigure[placeholder][width=27mm,height=27mm]}
    \input knuth
    \stophangaround
  \stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

Is there a way to support floats inside frames? Or is there another object which can provide a background colour that plays nicely with floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `textbackgrounds`

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\setupcolors[state=start]

\definetextbackground
  [imagebackground]
  [
    location=paragraph,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=green,
    frame=on,
  ]

\starttext

  \startimagebackground
  \placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[placeholder][width=27mm,height=27mm]}
  \input knuth
  \stopimagebackground

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Unlike frames, textbackgrouds can break across pages. So you might have to add a manual `\page` to avoid that.